# How to run a method before all tests in all classes?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I'm writing selenium tests, with a set of classes, each class containing several tests.  Each class currently opens and then closes Firefox, which has two consequences:

- super slow, opening firefox takes longer than running the test in a class...
- crashes, because after firefox has been closed, trying to reopen it really quickly, from selenium, results in an 'Error 54'

I could solve the error 54, probably, by adding a sleep, but it would still be super slow.

So, what I'd like to do is reuse the same Firefox instances across *all* test classes.  Which means I need to run a method before all test classes, and another method after all test classes.  So, 'setup_class' and 'teardown_class' are not sufficient.

Comment: Setting the [`scope`](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#working-with-a-module-shared-fixture) to `module` isn't enough?

Comment: I need a function to run once, right at the end, to shutdown the webbrowser.  I dont want to shut down the webbrowser after each class/module.  Nor do I want it never to be shut down.

Comment: Then it is pretty easy:  use the [`atexit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) and register the function that will close firefox to be executed right before the interpreter exits.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd prefer a 'py.test' way of doing it if possible.

Comment: You can do [module-level teardown and setup](http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html#module-level-setup-teardown) and I was using session-level teardowns and setups, however not sure if they are still available.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You might want to use a session-scoped "autouse" fixture:

```
# content of conftest.py or a tests file (e.g. in your tests or root directory)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def do_something(request):
    # prepare something ahead of all tests
    request.addfinalizer(finalizer_function)
```

This will run ahead of all tests. The finalizer will be called after the last test finished.

Comment: This won't work if i want to include a function scoped fixture to be used in this function

Comment: Will this run before each test or a total of once before testing?

Comment: This will be called once for each worker, if running tests in parallel. That might be what you want, or it might not be (e.g. a shared resource such as Firefox or a database).

Answer (score 142):

Using session fixture as suggested by [hpk42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844938/347181) is great solution for many cases,
but fixture will run only after all tests are collected.

Here are two more solutions:

#### conftest hooks

Write a [`pytest_configure`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) or [`pytest_sessionstart`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart) hook in your `conftest.py` file(see where to put conftest.py file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520971/248616))

```
# content of conftest.py


def pytest_configure(config):
    """
    Allows plugins and conftest files to perform initial configuration.
    This hook is called for every plugin and initial conftest
    file after command line options have been parsed.
    """


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    """
    Called after the Session object has been created and
    before performing collection and entering the run test loop.
    """
    

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    """
    Called after whole test run finished, right before
    returning the exit status to the system.
    """
    

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    """
    called before test process is exited.
    """
```

#### pytest plugin

Create a [pytest plugin](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html) with `pytest_configure` and `pytest_unconfigure` hooks.
Enable your plugin in `conftest.py`:

```
# content of conftest.py

pytest_plugins = [
    'plugins.example_plugin',
]
    

# content of plugins/example_plugin.py
def pytest_configure(config):
    pass


def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    pass
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Put a `conftest.py` in the same directory as your other tests that you wish to run with the same `pytest_sessionstart` and `pytest_sessionfinish` routines.

Comment: I think this does not work if the tests are spread across multiple files

Comment: This absolutely works when tests are split across many files.

Comment: Is there a solution for async function ?
I need to be my pytest_configure run async .

Answer (score 41):

Starting from version 2.10 there is a cleaner way to tear down the fixture as well as defining its scope. So you may use this syntax:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def my_fixture():
    print('INITIALIZATION')
    yield param
    print('TEAR DOWN')
```

**The autouse parameter:**
From [documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html):

> Here is how autouse fixtures work in other scopes:
>
> - autouse fixtures obey the scope= keyword-argument: if an autouse fixture has scope='session' it will only be run once, no matter where
>   it is defined. scope='class' means it will be run once per class, etc.
> - if an autouse fixture is defined in a test module, all its test functions automatically use it.
> - if an autouse fixture is defined in a conftest.py file then all tests in all test modules below its directory will invoke the fixture.
>
> ...

**The "request" parameter:**
Note that the "request" parameter is not necessary for your purpose although you might want to use it for other purposes. From [documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html):

> "Fixture function can accept the request object to introspect the
> “requesting” test function, class or module context.."

Answer (score 15):

Try to use [`pytest_sessionstart(session)`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart) in `conftest.py`

Example:

```
# project/tests/conftest.py

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    print('BEFORE')
```

```
# project/tests/tests_example/test_sessionstart.py

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def fixture():
    print('FIXTURE')


def test_sessonstart():
    print('TEST')
```

Log:

```
BEFORE
============================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/user/Documents/test, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: allure-pytest-2.8.12, env-0.6.2
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                             

tests/6.1/test_sessionstart.py::test_sessonstart FIXTURE
TEST
PASSED
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the  ```autouse=True``` fixture to record additional xml attributes using the ```record_xml_attribute``` fixture , but it only seems to be working on my local machine and not in the CI pipeline