# What is conftest.py for in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, conftest, pytest-fixtures

I'm trying to understand what `conftest.py` files are meant to be used for.

In my (currently small) test suite I have one `conftest.py` file at the project root. I use it to define the fixtures that I inject into my tests.

I have two questions:

1. Is this the correct use of `conftest.py`? Does it have other uses?
2. Can I have more than one `conftest.py` file? When would I want to do that? Examples will be appreciated.

More generally, how would you define the purpose and correct use of `conftest.py` file(s) in a pytest test suite?

Comment: You had me at `It seems great. However, I feel the documentation could be better.`

Comment: Yeah, the documentation could be so much better.  I searched the entire pytest documentation for `conftest.py` and although there are many references to doing this thing or doing that thing with a conftest file, nowhere in the documentation does it ever indicate that **when pytest does test discovery,** ***all conftest.py files found*** (within the directory strucutre over which test discovery is being done) ***will be run during the test collection phase*** (before any tests are run).  Had to figure that out myself via experimentation.

Answer (score 656, accepted):

> Is this the correct use of conftest.py?

Yes it is. Fixtures are a potential and common use of `conftest.py`. The
fixtures that you will define will be shared among all tests in your test suite. However, defining fixtures in the root `conftest.py` might be useless and it would slow down testing if such fixtures are not used by all tests.

> Does it have other uses?

Yes it does.

- **Fixtures**: Define fixtures for static data used by tests. This data can be accessed by all tests in the suite unless specified otherwise. This could be data as well as helpers of modules which will be passed to all tests.
- **External plugin loading**: `conftest.py` is used to import external plugins or modules. By defining the following global variable, pytest will load the module and make it available for its test. Plugins are generally files defined in your project or other modules which  might be needed in your tests. You can also load a set of predefined plugins as explained [here](https://pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html#requiring-loading-plugins-in-a-test-module-or-conftest-file).

  `pytest_plugins = "someapp.someplugin"`
- **Hooks**: You can specify hooks such as setup and teardown methods and much more to improve your tests. For a set of available hooks, read [Hooks link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#hooks). Example:

  ```
    def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
         """ called before ``pytest_runtest_call(item). """
         #do some stuff`
  ```
- **Test root path**: This is a bit of a hidden feature. By defining `conftest.py` in your root path, you will have `pytest` recognizing your application modules without specifying `PYTHONPATH`. In the background, py.test modifies your `sys.path` by including all submodules which are found from the root path.

> Can I have more than one conftest.py file?

Yes you can and it is strongly recommended if your test structure is somewhat complex. `conftest.py` files have directory scope. Therefore, creating targeted fixtures and helpers is good practice.

> When would I want to do that? Examples will be appreciated.

Several cases could fit:

Creating a set of tools or **hooks** for a particular group of tests.

**root/mod/conftest.py**

```
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    print("I am mod")
    #do some stuff


test root/mod2/test.py will NOT produce "I am mod"
```

Loading a set of **fixtures** for some tests but not for others.

**root/mod/conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture()
def fixture():
    return "some stuff"
```

**root/mod2/conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture()
def fixture():
    return "some other stuff"
```

**root/mod2/test.py**

```
def test(fixture):
    print(fixture)
```

Will print "some other stuff".

**Overriding** hooks inherited from the root `conftest.py`.

**root/mod/conftest.py**

```
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    print("I am mod")
    #do some stuff
```

**root/conftest.py**

```
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    print("I am root")
    #do some stuff
```

By running any test inside `root/mod`, only "I am mod" is printed.

You can read more about `conftest.py` [here](http://pytest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins.html).

**EDIT:**

> What if I need plain-old helper functions to be called from a number
> of tests in different modules - will they be available to me if I put
> them in a conftest.py? Or should I simply put them in a helpers.py
> module and import and use it in my test modules?

You can use `conftest.py` to define your helpers. However, you should follow common practice. Helpers can be used as fixtures at least in `pytest`. For example in my tests I have a mock redis helper which I inject into my tests this way.

**root/helper/redis/redis.py**

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_redis():
    return MockRedis()
```

**root/tests/stuff/conftest.py**

```
pytest_plugin="helper.redis.redis"
```

**root/tests/stuff/test.py**

```
def test(mock_redis):
    print(mock_redis.get('stuff'))
```

This will be a test module that you can freely import in your tests. **NOTE** that you could potentially name `redis.py` as `conftest.py` if your module `redis` contains more tests. However, that practice is discouraged because of ambiguity.

If you want to use `conftest.py`, you can simply put that helper in your root `conftest.py` and inject it when needed.

**root/tests/conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_redis():
    return MockRedis()
```

**root/tests/stuff/test.py**

```
def test(mock_redis):
    print(mock_redis.get(stuff))
```

Another thing you can do is to write an installable plugin. In that case your helper can be written anywhere but it needs to define an entry point to be installed in your and other potential test frameworks. See [this](https://pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html).

If you don't want to use fixtures, you could of course define a simple helper and just use the plain old import wherever it is needed.

**root/tests/helper/redis.py**

```
class MockRedis():
    # stuff
```

**root/tests/stuff/test.py**

```
from helper.redis import MockRedis

def test():
    print(MockRedis().get(stuff))
```

However, here you might have problems with the path since the module is not in a child folder of the test. You should be able to overcome this (not tested) by adding an `__init__.py` to your helper

**root/tests/helper/**init**.py**

```
from .redis import MockRedis
```

Or simply adding the helper module to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Without conftest.py, your test root path does not get added to the sys.path, and you will see errors like "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foobar'".

Comment: This is very helpful... but I'm a little confused by the statement "py.test modifies your sys.path by including all submodules which are found from the root path". I have two dirs under the root path, tests and src. src has one dir/package under it, "core", where the .py files are. From examining sys.path in the `__main__.py` file there during testing I can see that although the root dir and the "tests" dir are listed, neither "src" nor "src/core" is... which is problematic because it means `__main__.py` can't import sibling .py files as it can during a normal run (= not testing).

Answer (score 18):

In a wide meaning `conftest.py` is a local per-directory plugin. Here you define directory-specific hooks and fixtures. In my case a have a root directory containing project specific tests directories. Some common magic is stationed in 'root' `conftest.py`. Project specific - in their own ones. Can't see anything bad in storing fixtures in `conftest.py` unless they are not used widely (In that case I prefer to define them in test files directly)

Answer (score 18):

#### Update Pytest 7.2 (2023 - March)

Adding this answer because there are some comment regarding missing information in the docs, which I guess was back when this question was first asked, but now is very well explained and documented.

From **[conftest.py: sharing fixtures across multiple files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files)** till the bottom of the page (and actually anything related to fixture or setting up pytest can be applied to the `conftest.py`) is related to `conftest.py`

Therefore, by quickly scanning the docs these are the main functionality (but not inclusive) :

- Serve **fixtures** to tests (no matter the fixture scope)
- Modularize the available fixture for each `conftest.py` in a Tree like hierarchy
- Scope: sharing fixtures across classes, modules, packages or session
- Child `conftest.py` **can override** parent `conftest.py` (but not the opposite) [See this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#override-a-fixture-on-a-folder-conftest-level)
- Serve **fixtures** from a `third-party plugins`
- Loading and Sharing test data across multiple tests
- [Using fixtures from other projects](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#using-fixtures-from-other-projects)
- Serve and share [Hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#declaring-new-hooks)

Now on the accepted answer, it says **Test root path: : This is a bit of a hidden feature. By defining ...** but as for now, the best way to do this is instead add *`pythonpath`* to a `pytest.ini` on the root of your project (the actual project root, not `project/tests` ) see: [pythonpath](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath) and does all for you and is more powerfull

Which looks like

```ini
[pytest]
pythonpath = src1 src2
```

Lastly, here I drop one of **the many** graphs that are in the pytest docs about
*The boundaries of the scopes can be visualized like this:*

[image]

Answer (score 16):

> I use the `conftest.py` file to define the fixtures that I inject into my tests, is this the correct use of `conftest.py`?

**Yes**, a fixture is usually used to get data ready for multiple tests.

> Does it have other uses?

**Yes**, a fixture is a function that is run by `pytest` before, and sometimes
after, the actual test functions. The code in the fixture can do whatever you
want it to. For instance, a fixture can be used to get a data set for the tests to work on, or a fixture can also be used to get a system into a known state before running a test.

> Can I have more than one `conftest.py` file? When would I want to do that?

First, it is possible to put fixtures into individual test files. However, to share fixtures among multiple test files, you need to use a `conftest.py` file somewhere centrally located for all of the tests. Fixtures can be shared by any test. They can be put in individual test files if you want the fixture to only be used by tests in that file.

Second, **yes**, you can have other `conftest.py` files in subdirectories of the top tests directory. If you do, fixtures defined in these lower-level `conftest.py` files will be available to tests in that directory and subdirectories.

Finally, putting fixtures in the `conftest.py` file at the test root will make them available in all test files.

Answer (score 11):

Here are the official docs about using [conftest.py to share fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/fixtures.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files):

> **`conftest.py`: sharing fixtures across multiple files**
>
> The `conftest.py` file serves as a means of providing fixtures for an entire directory. Fixtures defined in a `conftest.py` can be used by any test in that package without needing to import them (pytest will automatically discover them).
>
> You can have multiple nested directories/packages containing your tests, and each directory can have its own `conftest.py` with its own fixtures, adding on to the ones provided by the `conftest.py` files in parent directories.

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple [conftest.py](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files).

For example, `tests1/test_1.py` can only access `tests1/conftest.py` as shown below:

```
project
 |-tests1
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  |-conftest.py # <- 〇
 |  |-test_1.py # Here
 |  └-subtests
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     |-conftest.py # <- ✖
 |     └-test_2.py
 └-tests2
    |-__init__.py
    |-conftest.py # <- ✖
    |-test_1.py
    └-subtests
       |-__init__.py
       |-conftest.py # <- ✖
       └-test_2.py
```

And, `tests1/subtests/test_2.py` can only access  `tests1/subtests/conftest.py` and `tests1/conftest.py` as shown below. * If there are the same name fixtures(functions) in `tests1/subtests/conftest.py` and `tests1/conftest.py`, then the fixture(function) in `tests1/subtests/conftest.py` is prioritized to access by `tests1/subtests/test_2.py`:

```
project
 |-tests1
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  |-conftest.py # <- 〇
 |  |-test_1.py 
 |  └-subtests
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     |-conftest.py # <- 〇
 |     └-test_2.py # Here
 └-tests2
    |-__init__.py
    |-conftest.py # <- ✖
    |-test_1.py
    └-subtests
       |-__init__.py
       |-conftest.py # <- ✖
       └-test_2.py
```