# How to connect allure reporting plugin to pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, allure

I am unable to connect allure plugin to pycharm, so that it can automatically generate the reports in the ./report/ directory.

I am unable to understand the https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python above documentation, it has a line which says **Connecting to IDE:**

**pytest_plugins = 'allure.pytest_plugin'**
But I am unable to understand where I need to make that change in pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `run>Edit Configurations>Python Tests` and add this line in `Additional Arguments`:

```
--alluredir=./reports/<report-name>
```

Pytest requires alluredir argument to create allure report. Once the allure report is created, you can serve it by this command in terminal:
`allure serve reports/<report-name>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create file `py.test` configuration file `conftest.py`. And put the string you mentioned there.
Don't forget to `import pytest` at the top of the file.

Comment: py.test is a text file contains nothing? and put `pytest_plugins = 'allure.pytest_plugin'` in the conftest.py file?

Comment: No need to create file py.test. You need only to create config file for py.test framework conftest.py. More about conftest.py https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/in-py-test-what-is-the-use-of-conftest-py-files and https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html