# Best way to use python-dotenv with pytest, or best way to have a pytest test/dev-environment with seperate configs

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, environment-variables, pytest

I want to use the python dotenv-lib at my python project. My dev-environment should use .env-file and the test-suite (pytest) should use .env.test automatically.

Until now I didn't find a satisfying solution.

I'm not very familiar with python. Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction.

Should I load the .env.test file in a pytest hook?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For anyone coming in 2019 or later:

You can use [pytest-dotenv](https://github.com/quiqua/pytest-dotenv) .

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Warning to Django Users: If you're using django-dotenv to call `dotenv.read_dotenv()` from your manage.py module, this library will break it. This library requires python-dotenv, which also uses the 'dotenv' namespace, and you'll end up a ModuleNotFoundError when manage.py is run.

Comment: while this may work, it is unclear to someone unfamiliar with pytest config on how to use it - even their code doesn't outline this, they just assume you know

Answer (score 6):

After some investigation I came to the conclusion of not using python-dotenv. I ended up using the cool library [simple-settings](https://github.com/drgarcia1986/simple-settings) and pytest [hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#well-specified-h). It solves my requirements quite well! simple-settings can load settings from several file-types. Which setting-file is loaded can be decided through an environment variable.

Following post can be very helpful, if somebody wants to learn something about pytest and its conftest file: [In py.test, what is the use of conftest.py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/in-py-test-what-is-the-use-of-conftest-py-files)

Here's my conftest.py file with two hooks implemented:

```
import os

def pytest_configure(config):
  os.environ['SIMPLE_SETTINGS'] = 'config.test'
  return config

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
  os.environ['SIMPLE_SETTINGS'] = 'config.development'
  return config
```

If I run some test with pytest the corresponding environment variable is set. So my test-suite uses automatically the right settings.

Answer (score 3):

In 2023, while `pytest-dotenv` is super helpful because it just works, I feel like it's a bit overkill since most projects probably already have `python-dotenv` installed. As a result, using a `conftest.py` file to setup a `pytest` fixture that loads your `.env` file can be done in 3 fairly simple steps!

### Steps

1. Add a `conftest.py` file to your `tests` folder
2. Import `pytest` and `from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv`
3. Define a `pytest` fixture

```
    @pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
    def load_env():
        env_file = find_dotenv('.env.tests')
        load_dotenv(env_file)
```

This `pytest` fixture works thanks to two key pieces.

First, setting the scope to `session` as well as `autouse=True` ensures this fixture runs before anything else.

Second, using `find_dotenv(file_name)` ensures the correct file path is used in `load_dotenv(file_path)` no matter what you call your `.env` file. If you do happen to call your test env file `.env`, then you can drop the `find_dotenv()` call and just run `load_dotenv()` without any arguments. `python-dotenv` should have no problem finding any typical `.env` files via `load_dotenv()`

That's it! Hopefully this helps, especially those that don't want to install another package to their project!

Comment: worked like a charm without any new dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I would use setUpClass() method to do it, which gets loaded before individual tests are run.

```
    class TestCases(Testcase):
    
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            from dotenv import load_dotenv
            load_dotenv(".dev-env")
    
        def test_myrandomtest():
            self.assert(something,something, "Oh crap")
```