# All my test functions are loading a fixture that is in the conftest.py, even when they don't need it

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have 2 different test files and some fixtures in my conftest.py:

1)"Test_dummy.py" which contains this function:

```py
def test_nothing():
    return 1
```

2)"Test_file.py". which contains this function:

```py
def test_run(excelvalidation_io):
    dfInput, expectedOutput=excelvalidation_io
    output=run(dfInput)
    for key, df in expectedOutput.items():
        expected=df.fillna(0)
        real=output[key].fillna(0)
        assert expected.equals(real)
```

3)"conftest.py" which contains these fixtures:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    inputfiles=glob.glob(DATADIR+"**_input.csv", recursive=False)
    iofiles=[(ifile, getoutput(ifile)) for ifile in 
    inputfiles]
    metafunc.parametrize("csvio", iofiles)
@pytest.fixture
def excelvalidation_io(csvio):
    dfInput, expectedOutput= csvio
    return(dfInput, expectedOutput)
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    client = app.test_client()
    return client
```

When i run the tests, "Test_dummy.py" also tries to load the "excelvalidation_io" fixture and it generates error:

```py
In test_nothing: function uses no argument 'csvio'
```

I have tried to place just the fixture inside the "Test_file.py" and the problem is solved, but i read that it's a good practice to locate all the fixtures in the conftest file.

Comment: But to be loaded at every test is what `conftest.py` is for, isn't it? Move your fixtures elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In pytest, what is the use of conftest.py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/in-pytest-what-is-the-use-of-conftest-py-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function **pytest_generate_tests** is a special function that is always called before executing any test, so in this case you need to check if the `metafunc` accepts an argument named "csvio" and do nothing otherwise, as in:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "excelvalidation_io" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        inputfiles=glob.glob(DATADIR+"**_input.csv", recursive=False)
        iofiles=[(ifile, getoutput(ifile)) for ifile in 
        inputfiles]
        metafunc.parametrize("csvio", iofiles)
```

[Source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example)