# Can the conftest.py file be put in another package aside the tests package for pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

**Question:**
Is it possible to put the **`conftest.py`** file into another package next to Test package as below structure?

**Description**
The project structure is as following:
--------------------------------------

```py
GUI_pytest
  - C_lib
      --__init__.py
      -- conftest.py
  - G_test<br/>
      --__init__.py
      -- test_2.py
```

**Source_Root:** `GUI_pytest`
**conftest.py:** `GUI_pytest/C_lib(package)`
**test_2.py(test file):** `GUI_pytest/G_test(package)`

`GUI_pytest/C_lib/conftest.py`:
there is a fixture function as **`def a()`**

test case: `GUI_pytest/G_test/test_2.py` uses the fixture as **`def test_2(a)`**

I want to split the `conftest.py` and `test_case().py` into **`C_lib package`** and **`G_test package`**

But the pytest seems not able to pick up the conftest.py file
Error not finding the fixture function **`a`** used by **`def test_2(a)`**

Thank you in advance
As a beginning learner, anything is welcome for helping this out.

Comment: Put it into the root path, if the content shall be used for all tests, and put separate `conftest.py` files with the test-specific stuff into the test paths, if needed.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen: May the ```conftest.py``` is put into another package as sibling to the ```test package```, I do not want to let the ```conftest.py``` under the root directory or mixing test files in test package.  Thank you very much! It is my first question's first replying.

Comment: `conftest.py` is not a test file, it is a configuration file - you can have as many as you like in different locations, and they will be used in the directory they are found in, or any subdirectories. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520971/12480730) are some related explanations (not sure I understood you correctly, though).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, thanks, not quite exact, the question is: 1) **root/lib/conftest.py** 2) **root/test/test_case.py**, how does **test_case.py** use the root/lib/conftest.py file? Because the pytest does not automatically load the **root/lib/conftest.py**? Thanks for your link which is also useful.

Comment: The lookup of  `conftest.py` is the same as the test lookup. I'm still not sure I get your problem. You have a fixture that is specific to a test, but you don't want to put it alongside the test, or at the parent directory? Something like this? Why has `conftest.py` to be under `C_lib`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, yes, yes, you got me, my god, yes, I really do not want to put the `conftest.py` under the root or alongside to the test, I want to put the `conftest.py` into another package `root\anotherpackage\conftest.py`, is that possible? Thank you again!!!

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, as the conftest.py is like a library file(from my opinion), so I make a `root/C_lib/` package to contain any lib files. So I put the conftest.py into `root/C_lib/` package.

Comment: The `conftest.py` is an extension of `pytest` specifically for your test suite. Keep it with your tests, not with your production code.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, thank you for clarifying that. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no, this is not possible without workarounds, and I would advice against it.

If you use a framework, you should use the conventions that the framework provides - this makes the usage easier, and you won't run into problems because of some usage that the framework does not expect. By framework here I mean `pytest`, which is more than an executable, as it provides (and expects) a certain infrastructure (which certainly could be documented better...). You can find more information for example in answers to the SO question [In pytest, what is the use of conftest.py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520971/12480730).

`pytest` uses `conftest.py` files to provide fixtures, plugins and hooks to tests in a hierarchical way.
So, say, you have the structure:

```
tests
   test_a
       test_a1.py
       test_a2.py
   test_b
       test_b1.py
       test_b2.py
```

where the tests in `test_a` use a fixture `local_fixture`, the tests in `test_b` use another fixture `local_fixture`, and all tests use the common fixture `common_fixture`. The easiest way to do this is the following:

```
tests
   conftest.py -> contains common_fixture
   test_a
       conftest.py -> contains local_fixture for test_a...
       test_a1.py
       test_a2.py
   test_b
       conftest.py -> contains local_fixture for test_b...
       test_b1.py
       test_b2.py
```

There can also be `conftest.py` files in plugins that are provided by other modules, and all of these fixtures you can just use without importing them, or doing some PYTHONPATH magic. You just have to go with the common conventions instead of using your own to be able to use that power.