# How do I run a pytest fixture once before all tests in a specific directory?

Tags: python, testing, scope, pytest

This is my directory structure:

```
test_directory/
├── test_feature_1/
│   ├── test1.py
│   └── test2.py
└── test_feature_2/
    ├── test3.py
    └── test4.py
```

I want to run a fixture function ONCE and then execute each of the tests in `test_feature_1` directory. After that, teardown the fixture. I do not want to execute this fixture for other tests in other directories.

Which scope should I use and where should I define my `conftest.py`? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/in-pytest-what-is-the-use-of-conftest-py-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In pytest, what is the use of conftest.py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/in-pytest-what-is-the-use-of-conftest-py-files)