# How to make pytest fail if print exists?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pytest

How can I make `pytest` fail if there is a `print` statement in the code?

Also (for security it can be useful), it will be great if the print does not actually get executed or shown in the CI.

Comment: Do you mean semantic print statements in code, or stdout/stderr output, the first is solved with parsing, the latter by collecting output from subprocess.

Comment: I mean semantic print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use session scope autouse fixture for `print` monkey patching , like so:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def mock_print():
    with mock.patch("builtins.print", side_effect=Exception('Print is not allowed!')) as _fixture:
        yield _fixture
```

Put this fixture in the `conftest.py` file, which is located in your `test` directory. We can define the fixture functions in this file to make them accessible across multiple test files. You can read more about this file here:

[In pytest, what is the use of conftest.py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34466027/13782669)

https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/fixture.html?highlight=conftest#sharing-a-fixture-across-tests-in-a-module-or-class-session

Comment: so do I need to add this this decorator on each separate `def test_` ?

Comment: Just insert it to root conftest file in test directory

Comment: What is the `root conftest file`?