# Importing a local file within a module, in its entirety, in the fewest possible lines

Tags: python, pytest, python-import, python-module

Say that I'm writing a **custom PIP package** which is structured like so:

```
.
|    setup.py
│
└─── src
|   |    __init__.py
|   |    useful_functions_i.py
|   |    useful_functions_ii.py
|   |    useful_strings.py
|
└─── tests
    |    unit_tests.py
```

Say that `useful_strings` looks something like this:

```py
USEFUL_STRING_A = "useful-string-a"
USEFUL_STRING_B = "useful-string-b"
...
```

And `useful_functions_i` and `useful_functions_ii` contain functions which do things like:

```py
def a_useful_function(a_string):
    if a_string == useful_strings.USEFUL_STRING_XYZ:
        return True
    return False
```

**How should I import `useful_strings` into `useful_functions_i` and `useful_functions_ii`?** (This isn't *quite* as straightforward a question as it might appear.)

If I use:

```py
import useful_strings
```

That will work well if I try to run some of the code in `src` locally; it will raise an exception if I run `pip install .` and try to use the codebase as a PIP package.

The next alternative is:

```py
from . import useful_strings
```

This works well if I try to use the codebase as a PIP package. The problem comes when I run the unit tests. I use **PyTest**; my `pytest.ini` starts with:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = src
testpaths = tests
...
```

And, if I were writing a unit test for `a_useful_function()` as defined above, the corresponding test script would contain the following import syntax:

```py
from src.useful_functions_i import a_useful_function
```

When running a unit test under these conditions, the `from . import useful_strings` syntax raises an exception.

I came across a workaround on another answer on this site. (I forget which one.) It looks like this:

```py
if __package__:
    from . import useful_strings
else:
    import useful_strings
```

This does work, and it's a solution that's peppered throughout the repos I'm currently working on. But it feels hacky, repetitive and unpythonic. **Is there a better way of doing this?** (It also makes PyLint complain about import orders, and, while I can live with that, it's becoming an irritation.)

Comment: how are you expecting this package to be used?  e.g. if I do a `pip install ...` what would I `import` to access `a_useful_function`

Comment: @SamMason Either: (A) `from my_package.useful_functions import a_useful_function`, or (B) I put an `from .useful_functions import a_useful_function` in `__init__.py` and call `from my_package import a_useful_function` in the external code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only running your code "locally" (I think this is the term you're using to say when you're developing/running from the command line)  that's the problem.  I'd use the following syntax to import packages:

```
from . import useful_strings
```

but you need to make sure Python knows that you're in a package when you run the code.  So running something like:

```bash
python -m src.entrypoint
```

(i.e. instead of `python src/entrypoint.py`) and you should be okay.

I'd also suggest using "[src-layout](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout)" or "[flat-layout](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#flat-layout)", as indicated in the [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/).  Creating a `conftest.py` file in the root can help pytest find the source code as well, so tests could `import my_package` instead of referring to `src` as well, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/pythonpath.html for more details or search for `PYTHONPATH` in [In pytest, what is the use of conftest.py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34466027/1358308).

Comment: Thank you for a valiant effort, but I'm not a fan of this answer: (1) Typing out `python -m src.entrypoint` every time I want to run my code is arguably more cumbersome than my current solution, and it doesn't address the PyTest edgecase. (2) Am I not using src-layout already? (3) I know a `conftest.py` file can be a useful trick in some cases, but, in my situation, it doesn't help, and actually breaks some tests that had been working.

Comment: (1) my shell lets me just hit the "up" key or use the reverse search features to easily rerun commands, i.e. it's mostly two key presses.  (2) you'd want your code in `src/my_package` and not directly under `src`. maybe see what other established projects do, e.g. https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs  (3) yup, it's likely to change imports, but having test code be more similar to idiomatic usage often helps, e.g. you don't have to remember to do something different for tests / users can refer to tests to see how to use the library.