# Empty __init__ and conftest files

Tags: python, pytest, init, conftest

Is there any usage of empty `__init__.py` or `conftest.py` files in Python? Today I've had a discussion about it in my team and someone said that they may have an importance in testing with Pytest and checking code coverage.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/in-pytest-what-is-the-use-of-conftest-py-files

Comment: empty `__init__.py`  are often necessary. I would not advise removing them... [read this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

Comment: Empty `__init__.py` causes that a directory becomes package, it has nothing to do with `conftest` actually.

Answer (score 1):

Conftest file is used by pytest to provide fixtures : [Official doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files)

For `__init__.py`, it is used to declare packages, and ca be used to search modules in your directories. It can also be used to initialise code (this is the first thing that is executed when you import a module): [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

So, both are useful.

Comment: Hi what the reason to have empty conftest.py?

Comment: If I remember correctly, pytest will add the directory containing confest.py in the sys.path. I don't know why and it may be just people struggling to understand how it works, but I know sometimes people just place it so that tests can be discovered, because it changes the behavior of pytest.

Comment: in nutshell we don't need it.
What will be break in case we don't put empty conftest.py in the test directory?

Comment: Your test "could" not be detected anymore. Just try it out, if  it stills work, then I would suggest you to still keep it, so you know where to put configuration for your tests later ;).