# How to pass variables during pytest call via python script(not command line)?

Tags: python, plugins, pytest

I am trying to run a test using pytest environment within a python script. I need the parameter called *config* which is defined in script.py to be used by the file 'test_functions.py'
Below is my implementtion .

However I get the error

> ```
> E       fixture 'config' not found  available fixtures: anyio_backend, anyio_backend_name, anyio_backend_options, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, info, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>   use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.`
> ```

**contents of script.py**

```
import pytest

if __name__ == '__main__':
   
    config = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
        # Add more key-value pairs as needed
    }


    class MyPlugin(object):
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data

        @pytest.fixture
        def info(self, request):
            return self.data

    myplugin = MyPlugin(config)

    pytest.main(['test_functions.py'],plugins=[myplugin])
```

**content of test_functions.py'** is as follows

```
def test_function(config):
    # Access the config dictionary
    print(config['monthly_or_weekly'])
    assert config['value1']=='value2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `config` as a fixture in your test, but `config` isn't being defined as one in your code. You want something like this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def config():
    yield {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
    }

def test_function(config):
    print(config['key1'])
    print(config['key2'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response -- I am trying to define the fuction  def test_function in a seperate file and invoke the test with the expression pytest.main(['test_function.py'])-- We need to pass this fixture config during the call.

Comment: You can define your fixtures in a ``conftest.py`` file so that they are available to all tests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520971/7058266

Answer (score 0):

We can use config file  in PyTest like this: **pytest --variables mac_capabilities.json ./demo.py**. check it out - "https://pypi.org/project/pytest-variables/"
*should have  pytestvariables*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).