# How to pass a fixture as param to another fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I want to pass a `pytest.fixture` function to another fixture function's param argument. Something like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def foo():
    return "foo"

@pytest.fixture()
def boo(foo):
    return foo + "boo"

@pytest.fixture()
def bar(foo):
    return foo + "bar"

@pytest.fixture(params=[boo, bar], ids=["boo_fixture", "bar_fixture"])
def final_fixture(request):
    return request.param

def _test(final_fixture):
    assert final_fixture.startswith('foo')
```

The `request.param` in `final_fixture` returns the function object for that param, instead of the return value of the fixtures(`boo` and `bar`)

```
<function boo at 0x7f2bfceg41f0>
<function bar at 0x7f2bfceg41f1>
```

So, how can I make the `final_fixture` function return the actual return values for each fixture `param`?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible: See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035775/9978789 and https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html

Comment: @PhilippSelenium I have found a solution for this below. Thanks for linking the pytest issue. There was a mention of a similar approach there as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42599627/12523711) answer by Will.

It seems like you can just use `request.getfixturevalue` to get the return value of the fixture instead of the function object. Here is the working code for this:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def foo():
    return "foo"

@pytest.fixture()
def boo(foo):
    return foo + "boo"

@pytest.fixture()
def bar(foo):
    return foo + "bar"

@pytest.fixture(params=['boo', 'bar'], ids=["boo_fixture", "bar_fixture"])
def final_fixture(request):
    return request.getfixturevalue(request.param)

def _test(final_fixture):
    assert final_fixture.startswith('foo')
```

Here is the related doc: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue

Comment: So we should probably close this question as duplicate

Comment: I am not sure if that's the right thing to do here. Atleast the question isn't duplicate, the other one talked about passing fixtures to `parametrize`, this is for passing fixtures to `fixture`. I agree that the answer could be very similar since its borrowed from there. Besides, it took me a lot of searches to find that question, since the keywords were not matching initially. :)