# Selenium error in Jenkins server but passes on local machine and remote machines

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on selenium python tests. In my local machine(windows) and remote machine(ubuntu and in headless mode) tests run fine. But on Jenkins pipeline the tests are failing.
On remote and jenkins, Selenium version is same 4.1.3. Firefox version is same 98.0.1.

The first test fails with error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a href="/text/funct/num/"> could not be scrolled into view`

The window location and size prints same values for in all (windows, remote ubuntu and jenkins) machines

```
  print(browser.driver.get_window_size())
  print(browser.driver.get_window_position())
```

```
Output is same:
{'width': 1366, 'height': 768}
{'x': 0, 'y': 0}
```

I am trying to understand the issue.
How should I debug further.

I am looking for a universal solution for all the errors since I am facing errors in multiple tests.

I have tried setting windows size but it didn't help.

```
    self.driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

I have printed the page source `self.driver.page_source` and I see the element `<a href="/text/funct/num/">` is present in html as  `<td><a href="/text/funct/num/"><i class="val"></i></a></td>`

Comment: Do you have any screenshots for when you get the element not interactable exception? That might tell you if your application is rendering correctly on the headless instance.

Comment: No, how to get that

Comment: You have to add a take screenshot call to your try catch in your script. See how to take a screenshot with selenium in python, and an @after function here if you're using python with pytest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801300/how-to-run-a-method-before-all-tests-in-all-classes

Comment: The screenshot feature helped. I see in windows and remote machine's screenshot's element  which I am trying to click is present but in jenkins screenshot the element to click is not at all present..